# In a Silverstripe DB where can I find the Users table and Password?

Tags: database, silverstripe

I have a local Silverstripe instance but I cannot login and the owners are battling to find their login details. I have the DB so how can I find the Users table and edit it, or make myself an admin account? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite having solved your problem, you did not answer your own question :-). For Google's sake I will try...

The user table is called "Member". It has got the email address and the password in it. You can not manually change the password here, as it is hashed. What you can do is change the email address and use the "forgot password" functionality (in case the client can't do that himself), change the password for the client through the application backend (cms) and change the email address back to its original value. If you are wondering what the MemberPassword table does: AFAIK it only stores a copy of all used passwords by a user (password history)

When you want to make an account administrator, you should first take a look at the Group table and look for "administrators" in the "Code" Column. Take that ID (normally, this would be 2). After that, take a look in the Member table, and look for the user you want to make an admin. Take the ID here as well.

Next, open the Group_Member table and insert a new row (or change the existing if you want) and specify the group id under GroupID and the member id under MemberID.

Adding Security::setDefaultAdmin('admin','admin'); to the _config.php also works, but don't forget to remove it afterwards, just as any phpmyadmin or equivalent that you installed :-)

Comment: Thanks you are right even though I found a workaround it did not answer my original question. Thanks for explaining that :)

Answer (score 2):

Just found this add `Security::setDefaultAdmin('username', 'password');` to mysite/_config.php. Worked like a bomb!

Answer (score 1):

Create a file _ss_environment.php in the webroot (or the folder above it) if it doesn't already exist. Add these two lines to the bottom:

`define('SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME','admin');
define('SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD','password');`

Comment: What would be the advantage of this compared to the Security::setDefaultAdmin('username', 'password')?

Comment: _ss_environment.php can be created outside of your project, and apply to multiple Silverstripe projects operating on the same webserver. If it's outside of your project, there's no risk of inadvertently committing something sensitive (like a password or a private key) to your version control history.